# Magento Products are not listed on fronend

Tags: magento-1.5

I downloaded a old magento site and installed it on my local server. My admin panel is working perfect but products are not listed in frontend. Links on the front end page are also not working.
I have reindexed data, cleared cache, my urls also updated in database, increased memory_limits but nothing is working.....

Comment: check magento log file for error descriptions.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Are you sure the products are enabled, visible, in stock and linked to your website(s)? You might want to remove all entries from the `core_url_rewrite` table and reindex again